# When I call the method stopservice(), after interval minutes will start, you do not cancel it mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent)?

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

```
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private void setAlarm() {
    interval = mPreferences.getInt(
    ServerMonitorPlus.REQUEST_STATUS_INTERVAL_DATA, 300);
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, interval);
    mIntent = new Intent("com.receiver");
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            mPendingIntent);
}
```

---

I set up a alarm start automatically every interval minutes.

---

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent);
    destoryTimerTask();
}
```

---

Cancel it when I call `stopservice()`.

---

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setAlarm();
}
```

---

***Question:***

When I call the method `stopservice()`, after `interval` minutes will start, you do not cancel it `mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent)`?